I am trying to install Clarity App from Microsoft store for a SharePoint site, but it gives an error in the last step. What is the solution?
Steps from the MS document
PowerShell screenshot
I tried executing all the steps mentioned in the document(Shared as a image) but failed to execute the last step(refer to the PowerShell screenshot). I need to install the App for a specific SharePoint site.
